# Template class stops another class from working

Tags: php, class, templates

Trying to get a simple template system working, but it seems to affect another class.

I have two PHP classes, both called in index.php:

- HeaderData.php - class allows user to setup Header data, eg doctype,
  charset.
- PageTemplates.php - class allows user to include a template file.

When I call the HeaderData class, then *manually* `require()` a template file from view (ie contains doctype, head, meta tags etc), the code from the header class works fine in the template file, outputting the objects from the header class such as Doctype etc.

However, when I try to use the PagesTemplate class to include the template file (with manual `require()` removed from index.php), the template file is included, but the HeaderData class no longer works in it.
Error log shows:

- Notice: "Undefined variable varHeaderData";
- Error: "Call to a member function PageDoctype() on a non-object";

Both the variable and function worked fine when manually `require()` the template file in index.php.

The code below is dev only (data checks etc to be added):

**index.php:**

```
// Use HeaderData Class
$varHeaderData = new HeaderData( 
                            array(  
                                   'PageDoctype' => '<!DOCTYPE html>',
                                   'PageCharset' => 'UTF-8', 
                                  ));

// Use PageTemplates Class
$varPageTemplate = new PageTemplates();
$varPageTemplate->LoadTemplate('template-file.php');
```

**PageTemplates.php Class:**

```
class PageTemplates
  {

    private $strTemplatesDir = 'view/templates/';

    public function __construct($strTemplatesDir = NULL)
      {
        if ( is_dir($strTemplatesDir) )
          {
            $this->strTemplatesDir = $strTemplatesDir;
          }
      }


    public function LoadTemplate($strTemplateFile)
      {
         {
           require_once ($this->strTemplatesDir.$strTemplateFile);
         }
      }

  }
```

**template-file.php:**

```
echo $varHeaderData->PageDoctype();
```

The HeaderData class simply sets the object the user entered in the array with the `PageDoctype()` function in the class (again this works fine without the page template class)

Can someone tell me why when using the template class to `require()` the template file, it stops the objects from the HeaderData from working in the template-file.php?

Comment: When you require a file in `LoadTemplate` method, it doesn't see `$varHeaderData` because it is in different scope.

Comment: @barell I tried various ways using `ob_start()/flush()` etc in the template class, and then around the object call in index.php. Everything I tried stopped the HeaderData class from working in the template file. So how do I manage this to resolve the scope issue then please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to pass variable in to the `LoadTemplate` method as an array and use `extract` function:

```
public function LoadTemplate($strTemplateFile, $vars = array())
{
    extract($vars);
    require($this->strTemplatesDir.$strTemplateFile);
}
```

And in the index.php

```
...
$varPageTemplate->LoadTemplate('template-file.php', array(
    'varHeaderData' => $varHeaderData
));
```

One of your errors says: "Call to a member function PageDoctype() on a non-object", so make sure that `PageDoctype()` method is defined in the `HeaderData` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd have to pass in all sorts of vars from other classes to every template I load this way. Doesn't this ruin Polymorphism, most of the beauty of classes?

Comment: Another solution is to use `global` keyword. The answer I gave is used even in one of the most popular framework - Yii. Of course it is more complicated there but idea is the same. I don't know how it can collide with  polymorphism.

Comment: What I mean is, HeaderData class sets about 8 different things for Meta etc, then other classes (also used in the templates) set all sorts of data. Thanks for the answer anyway. I'll have a tinker and possibly read another framework's approach (wanted to avoid that so mine was not tainted, mine is for a small setup & intentionally not as scalable). Thanks again.

Comment: If you are using `HeaderData` class only to keep your meta tags and/or   updating it in templates files (or wherever), maybe better solution for you would be make `HeaderData` as a singleton.

Comment: Thanks for the additional thoughts. I'm don't know how singleton changes the scope, but will look into it. Ta